# Cannot disable transition animation when back button is clicked

Tags: android, android-activity

When I click the back button to go back to previous activity, the transition slide still occur even though I have added overridePendingTransition. What is wrong with my code?

I want to disable all transition between the activities. There is no animation on transition when going to new activity but slide out when back button is pressed.

```
Activity act;

Intent intent = new Intent(act, newactivity.class);
intent.setFlags(65536);
act.startActivity(intent); 
act.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should call `overridePendingTransition(0, 0);` in Activity's `onPause()`:

```
 public void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
 }
```

Comment: or in onBack() if your targeting Android > 1.5